# In requires parameter lists, can you introduce types that result in substitution failures?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++-concepts

For example, can I define a concept like

```
template <class Iter>                                                        
concept bool Iterator =                                                      
    requires(Iter i, typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type val,    
             typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::reference ref) {           
  ++i;                                                                       
  // other implementation                                                    
};
```

With gcc 6 this code will [compile](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/06evPgPPKSXbXDAw), but something like `Iterator<int>` will also result to `true` even though `val` and `ref` would be substitution failures. Is this what it's suppose to do?

Comment: I believe you are not allowed to write `Iterator<int>` outside a requires-clause or equivalent (as alluded to in section 4 of [N4434](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4434.pdf)), but I can't find the wording to that effect right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the latest public available draft [N4377](http://wg21.link/n4377), this is a *parameterized constraint* ([temp.constr.param]):

> A *parameterized constraint* is a constraint that declares a sequence
>   of parameters (8.3.5), called *constraint variables*, and has a single
>   operand. [ *Note*: Parameterized constraints are introduced by
>   *requires-expression*s (5.1.4). The constraint variables of a parameterized constraint correspond to the parameters declared in the
>   *requirement-parameter-list* of a *requires-expression*, and the operand of the constraint is the conjunction of constraints. — *end
>   note* ]

And that section explicitly contemplates substitution failures for constraint variables ([temp.constr.param]/2):

> A parameterized constraint is satisfied if and only substitution into
>   the types of its constraint variables does not result in an invalid
>   type, and its operand is satisfied. Template arguments are substituted
>   into the declared constraint variables in the order in which they are
>   declared. If substitution into a constraint variable fails, no more
>   substitutions are performed, and the constraint is not satisfied.

The behavior you observe appears to be a bug in the implementation.